# Calling NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler from Rubymotion

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I'm trying to hook up a global exception handler using `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` in a **Rubymotion** app. And I can't figure out how to do it, probably I'm using Rubymotion function pointer syntax incorrectly.

In `application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)` I have:

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler nil do |exception|
  NSLog "exception handler block"
  applicationFailedWithException(exception)
end
```

And the handler (which is never called):

```
def applicationFailedWithException(exception)
  NSLog "applicationFailedWithException"
end
```

Then, in runtime, when some NoMethodError happens somewhere neither the exception handler block, neither the handler method are called. I've tried both in the Simulator and on the device — no success.

P.S. Is there a way to get the ruby methods stack in the crash log, the last application method in the crash log is always the `rb_rb2oc_exc_handler` instead of the app-specific method, and that's weird.

Thanks

**Update 2015**

It seems that with the newer versions of the Rubymotion you have to save a references to the handler in an instance variable, otherwise it will not work. So it should look like:

```
def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
  @exceptionHandler = lambda { |exception| uncaughtExceptionHandler(exception) }

  # or you can use a method reference, which is the same
  # @exceptionHandler = method :uncaughtExceptionHandler

  NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler @exceptionHandler

  ...
end

def uncaughtExceptionHandler(exception)
  # log it or send it to crashlytics / flurry / whatever
  NSLog "Fatal exception catched\nName: #{exception.name}\nReason: # {exception.reason}\nInfo#{exception.userInfo}"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work, I had to assign a block to a variable, then use that variable:

```
handler = lambda do |exception|
  NSLog "Exception Name: #{exception.name}"
end
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(handler)
```

If I then punch in something like `NSException.raise("test", format: "test")` in the REPL, I'll see NSLog do it's thing:

```
2012-09-11 09:33:05.949 exc[14723:c07] Exception Name: test
2012-09-11 09:33:05.950 exc[14723:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'test', reason: 'test'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1647022 0x22bcd6 0x15efa48 0x15ef9b9 0x8f00743 0xe3c0c 0x8f0031a 0x8f000ad 0xd4c9fa2 0x259e8d9 0x259f509 0x157e803 0x157dd84 0x157dc9b 0x261f7d8 0x261f88a 0x563626 0x25d0 0x23b5)
terminate called throwing an exception%
```

Theoretically, you should be able to nest the lambda directly as the parameter rather than assigning it to a variable first, but I don't think RubyMotion properly retains the block and the application crashes without error if you try it.

Comment: Could the recent RM updates with regard to blocks and memory management have fixed the block retention issue?

Answer (score 1):

Dylan's answer is great. I am a big fan of passing methods as lambdas like this:

```
def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
  NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler method(:on_exception)
end

def on_exception(exception)
  puts "Exception Name: #{exception.name}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/ControllingAppResponse.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000473-BBCHGJIJ) you have to add `ExceptionHandling.framework` to your project. But even after:

```
Rakefile
Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  app.frameworks += %w(ExceptionHandling)
end
```

it doesn't work for OS X.